# Use mySQL to update availability of a property (airbnb-copycat)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, airbnb-js-styleguide

I am creating airbnb like app (for my portfolio) that allows people to rent a property for a short period. The app uses node.js and mysql for the backend.
I was wondering how the availability of the property would be handle in a mysql database. For example, let's say that a property is available in July and someone wants to rent it for a few days. How would you update the availability of the property for that the rented period so it appears as unavailable? How would this be communicated to a database such as mysql? what if the booking is cancelled and the property becomes available for that period again?

Comment: You need a date range on a booking and a status of some sorts.  This questions is too broad for SO.